# Loop through JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json, api, parsing, for-loop

I am still new to Python and at this moment I am experimenting with GET requests and only show values from one specific String.

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("APIURL")
data = response.text
parsed = json.loads(data)
id = parsed["products"][0]["id"]
print(id)
```

As you can see in the code above I don't have a for loop yet, already tried different things but still didn't get it working. With the code above I get the 'id' of only the first product, of the other products I don't get the results back.

The printed output, for the `dict` loaded from JSON, looks as follow:

```
{
    products: [
        {
            id: 66057248,
            createdAt: "2018-02-28T14:55:22+01:00",
            updatedAt: "2018-02-28T14:55:22+01:00",
            isVisible: true,
            visibility: "visible",
            hasMatrix: false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of diek is the one that worked for me, edited my post because of this. The better code is:

```
import requests
import json
response = requests.get("")
data =response.text
parsed=json.loads(data)

for product in parsed['products']:
    print(product['id'])
```

The output will look as follow:

```
66057248
66057245
66057242
66057239
66057236
66057233
66057230
66057227
66057224
```

Comment: Giving one item in your example was not clear. If the structure is 'products': [ {'id': 66057248}, {'id': 66057245},....], there is absolutely no need to use range and len

Comment: @diek Hmm what do you mean exactly? So how should it look in your opinion?

Comment: If your json is formatted like this, https://dpaste.de/RUzV
Then all you need is, https://dpaste.de/5gc2

Comment: @diek thanks for the code! That worked indeed. Could you explain to me what the main difference is between the code I used and the one you provided? Still new to Python so I am trying to understand everything as much as possible :)

Comment: First, Python makes iteration so much easier than other languages. You do not have to account for the length, Python manages this. If you want to get a good understanding of it, watch Ned Batchelder's PyCon video Loop Like a Native. 29 minutes well spent

Comment: Second, when I have data['products'], I have a list of dictionaries. No index is required. I then use the dictionary key, 'id', to access the value/data on each iteration. In more complex structures you may need to use an index to drill down

Comment: Thank you very much @diek for the information and for the video, much appreciated! I have edited my answer above as you can see :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
for product in parsed:
    for index in parsed[product]:
        for element in parsed[product][index]:
            print(element.id)
            print(element.createdAt)
            # ...
```

In Simon's answer the `id` value in the loop would actually be `'id'`, `'createdAt'` and etc. To print only ids as it suggests you need to assert if the key is equals to `'id'`, what makes the loop useless.

Note: It is not suggested to use `id` as variable name. It is a reserved word, in this case you can add the underscore getting `id_` instead.

Comment: Which values do I have to change to merge this with my existing code and which values do I have to remove from my existing code?

Comment: If I got your question right, if you change your 2 last lines for this `for`, it will print every `id` and `createdAt` for every element for every product in `parsed` dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Json uses a dictionary so you could use `keys()` to get all the possible values and then initerate through them:

```
for id in parsed["products"][0].keys():
    print(parsed["products"][0][id])
```

---

Figured it out:

This is not json.  It is YAML (because your code lacks `"` (speech marks)).  You need a YAML parser to run this.  Once you have then it will run correctly.

Comment: Hi I tried your code, maybe I did something wrong But my output looks as follow:

66057248
66057248
66057248
66057248
66057248
66057248


As you can see it keeps looping the first product over and over again and doesn't get the ID of the other products.

Comment: @Solaiman  What happens if you change the value of `id` as suggested below?  Do you get the same result?

Comment: yes forgot to mention , I had already changed the value of the id as suggested below. So yeah same results.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Simon , I managed to solve it. And it is json :P, anyway this code below worked:

import requests
import json
response = requests.get("")
data =response.text
parsed=json.loads(data)
for i in range(0,len(parsed["products"])):
    print(parsed["products"][i]["id"])

Comment: You could write your own answer and accept that rather than accept my answer.  You solution seems a lot different to mine. @Solaiman